# Getting highest grade and printing it out using arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I want to write a program that can read scores, get the best scores, and assign grades based on that. I have the general idea so far, my problem is figuring out how to incorporate the necessary `for-loops`. Another problem I have is figuring out how to change line 
----(String s1=input.next();) and have the final answer print out the number of entries entered.

I must also use the equation

Grade is A if best score if >= best-10

Grade is B if best score if >= best-20

Grade is C if best score if >= best-30

Grade is D if best score if >= best-40

**Ex solution:**

Enter number of Students: *4*

Enter *4* scores: *40* *55* *70* *58*

Student 0 score is *40* and grade is C

Student 1 score is *55* and grade is B

etc. to 4 students.

```
  public class Lab_7_1{
  public static void main(String[] args){
  java.util.Scanner input=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Enter the number of students: ");
  int n1=input.nextInt();
  int [] number=new int[n1];

  System.out.print("Enter "+n1+" Scores: ");
  String s1=input.next();



 }
}
```

Comment: .... what have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have tried adding a for loop with the int best=0 in it. However once I did that, it stopped allowing me to enter grades into program. I know this program requires a for loop to find the best score and a for loop to determine whether or not the grades are ABCDF. I can't figure out how to set up the loops

Comment: Have you considered just sorting the collection of scores?

Comment: We are told to use arrays, but I will figure it out eventually. I might end up visiting the tutor center and hopefully they can help me.

Comment: Check out Arrays.sort() at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: @jgitter You are jumping ahead, because OP hasn't figured out how to even get the numbers into the array, besides your comment won't allow printing "Student 0 score is...", because the sort lost the original order, so you no longer know which score belonged to "student 0".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

public class Lab_7_1{

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    java.util.Scanner input=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the number of students: ");
    int n1=input.nextInt();
    int [] number=new int[n1];

    System.out.print("Enter "+n1+" Scores: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
        number[i]=input.nextInt();
        int b=i+1;
        System.out.println("Score "+b+": "+number[i]);

    }
    int best = number[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {

        if (number[i]>best) best = number[i];
    }
    System.out.println("The best score is: "+best);

    for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
        if(number[i]>=best-20 && number[i]<=best-10) System.out.println("For score "+number[i] +" you get B grade.");
        if(number[i]>=best-30 && number[i]<=best-20) System.out.println("For score "+number[i] +" you get C grade.");
        if(number[i]>=best-40 && number[i]<=best-30) System.out.println("For score "+number[i] +" you get D grade.");
    }


}
}`
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, I guess I'll just go through and figure out what you did step by step.

Comment: Okay thank you. I have one question, before I asked the question I could not figure out why it would not let me enter number.length in the foor loop. it kept giving me error messages. Do you know what that could be from?

Comment: Maybe you have put () after length, i can't say anything without seeing the code..

Comment: Oh I found out what I did wrong. I used the wrong variable to put ".length" on.

Comment: Just check for the error text if you are using eclipse, it can explain a lot when you get into it.

Answer (score 0):

Next step ([using a `for` loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
    number[i] = input.nextInt();
}
```

Now that you've learned how to write a `for` loop, you can loop through the numbers to find the highest number, then do it again to print the results.

Comment: Thank you, so the "i" refers to the number of array, not the value inside right?

Comment: `i` is used as the index into the array.

Comment: And sorry if I wrote my question wrong, the for loop in general I understand. It was finding the best score but this helps either way.